# Blackberry SendListener is called multiple times

Tags: blackberry, java-me, sms, listener

I have the following code in my app which listens and increments the counter when an sms is sent.

```
    SendListener smsListener = new net.rim.blackberry.api.sms.SendListener() {

        public boolean sendMessage(Message message) {
            ++smsCount;
            return true;
        }
    };
```

However, for some reason the `sendMessage` method is called multiple times (usually this is 3 times) when only a single sms is send (even when the sms message is very short).

Why is this ? Is there a workaround for this problem ?

Comment: Is it possible that you have added the listener multiple times. You have three listener instances.

Comment: I dont think that's the case I checked I only have one and it's still being called multiple times

Comment: Check how long the message actually is. Some char encodings decrease the SMS max length, thus the original message has to be fragmented and each part is sent as a single message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find mention about this issue on bb dev forum. As Emmanuel suggested you probably register listener several times. Please review this thread:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/sendListener-sms-and-folder-listner-invalk-multiple-times/m-p/1978915/highlight/true#M211297

Comment: Thanks so much this actually helped a lot. I used a runtime object as a flag to make sure that I dont add the listener more than one time. I wish the docs were as detailed as this form. The docs actually say that if the listener object already exists its not added again so I thought it was not the case of adding multiple times.